# Alternative to Prism/chromeless/WebRunner available for production

Tags: chromeless, mozilla-prism

I really like the experiments from Mozilla with Mozilla-Prism.
I want to customize Firefox to remove address bar, tabs an open everytime to a single domain name.

All the solution I've found (Prism, Chromeless and WebRunner) are discontinuing.

Are there a safe for production equivalents ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) can be used to build cross-platform desktop applications with Web technologies.